# Compare values under multiple conditions of one column in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data:

```
data = {
    "index": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    "name": ["A", "A", "B", "B", "B"],
    "type": ['s1', 's2', 's1', 's2', 's3'],
    'value': [20, 10, 18, 32, 25]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I need to check if the value under same name follow constraint (say there only three type and not all exist under same name): s1 < s2 < s3, which means, under same name, if the value of s1 is smaller than s2 or s3, then return True, if s2 is smaller than s3, then return True. Otherwise, return False or NaN.
Here is the output I expected:

```
    index   name    type    value   result
0     1      A       s1      20      False
1     2      A       s2      10        
2     3      B       s1      18      True
3     4      B       s2      32      False
4     5      B       s3      25
```

How can I do it in Python? Thanks for your help.

Comment: what have you already try? please add some code

Comment: Why are there dashes in some rows and `False`s in some other rows? What is the formula/algorithm for calculating each `result`?

Comment: @DYZ For instance, under A there are only s1. It would return dash or NaN if you like.

Comment: Your question is unclear. _for instance_ isn't good enough. What _exactly_ is the condition for `True`, `False`, and dash - for each of the outcomes separately? Once you have the formula, it is easy to code it.

Comment: @DYZ A s1 return False because s1 is not smaller than s2 in example. Same reason for B s2.

Comment: Ok, what about `True` and a dash? Also, can you have more than one `s1`, `s2` or `s3` per name?

Comment: @DYZ group by `name`, now say there are three type `s1, s2 and s3`, then check if `s1` is less than `s2` if yes state `True` else `False`, now take next pair, `s2` and `s3`. Do same with this pair. Since we don't have any next pair to form with `s3` hence `-`

Comment: @meW That' just an educated guess. I'd rather know what the OP has in mind.

Comment: Sorry@DYZ, The formula for calculating each result is here: s1 < s2 < s3 and I have only one s1, s2 or s3 per name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
#Use pd.Categorical to ensure sorting if column is not lexicographical ordered.
df['type'] = pd.Categorical(df['type'], ordered=True, categories=['s1','s2','s3'])

df['result'] = df.sort_values('type').groupby('name')['value'].diff(-1)

df['result'] = df['result'].lt(0).mask(df['result'].isna(),'')

df
```

Output:

```
   index name type  value result
0      1    A   s1     20  False
1      2    A   s2     10       
2      3    B   s1     18   True
3      4    B   s2     32  False
4      5    B   s3     25
```

Comment: why `sort_values('type')`. Answer still comes without it. Am I missing something?

Comment: If the dataframe isn't sored by type, then diff will not work correctly.  Diff(-1) takes the current row and subracts the next row regardless of sort.  So, to get diff the perform as expected wit s1<s2<s3, then you need to sort to ensure proper calculation.  If your dataframe is already sorted by s1<s2<s3, then you don't need to.